# Not able to perform update using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, transactions, hql

I want to update my `Users` table, but I'm not able to update it. and getting some error

```
String username = resetuser;
Session hbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Users user = (Users) hbsession.get(Users.class, username);
user.setPassword(encryptpasswd1);
user.setSecure(salt);

hbsession.getTransaction().commit();
```

Could not complete request

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:172)
    at com.iserve.mis.controller.UserController.storepassword(UserController.java:255)
    at com.iserve.mis.controller.UserController.confirmPassword(UserController.java:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? It says: Transaction not successfully started . You're trying to commit a transaction but you never started it.

Comment: To be fair, it's a poor error message though because it sounds like something went wrong inside the db; "Cannot call commit() on a session that is not participating in a transaction. Call beginTransaction() first" or something more clearly implying it was user error would have been better :)

Comment: Thanks JB Nizat, it was silly mistake from my side

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JB Nizet, 
Actually i forgot to begin the transaction.
After adding        **hbsession.beginTransaction()** i am able to update my database